# Questions about North Germanic languages

Tags: support

Are questions about North Germanic languages on topic here?

Is it ok to ask about Swedish language here?

Comment: There **was** a Swedish Language & Usage proposal. Unfortunately it didn't receive enough attention and [it got deleted](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/30894/swedish-language-usage). You can re-propose it, if you want.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, questions about Scandinavian languages are *off topic* here. Exceptions are questions that relate to German somehow like translations to or from German.